# Number theory : properties of the first prime numbers 2,3,5,7

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p,q,r$ and $s$ be four distinct prime numbers chosen among the set $\{2,3,5,7\}$ and we look for all the $4$-tuples of integers > 0  $(a,b,c,d)$ such that: $$p^a = q^b + (r^c)\cdot(s^d)$$

There are $4!$ = $24$ possible ways to choose the four values of $p,q,r,$ and $s$ which give $12$ different equations.

Prove that for at least $10$ different equations, there exists at least one solution in $(a,b,c,d)$.

For example: with $p=7, q=5, r=3, s = 2,$ and $a=2, b = 2, c = 1,$ and $d= 3$, we have the relation $7^2 = 5^2 + (3^1)\cdot (2^3)$.

For each equation having at least one solution, is there a finite or infinite number of solutions?

Comment: What have you done so far? For example list the 12 equations, try to find at least one solution for 10 of them, ...

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following solutions:

p=7 q=5 r=2 s=3 ==> 1 solution a=2 b=2 c=3 d=1

p=7 q=3 r=2 s=5 ==> 2 solutions a=2 b=2 c=3 d=1 and a=3 b=5 c=2 d=2

p=7 q=2 r=3 s=5 ==> 1 solution a=2 b=2 c=2 d=1

p=5 q=7 r=2 s=3 ==> 2 solutions a=2 b=1 c=1 d=2 and a=4 b=2 c=6 d=2

p=5 q=3 r=2 s=7 ==> 1 solution a=3 b=3 c=1 d=2

p=5 q=2 r=3 s=7 ==> 1 solution a=3 b=3 c=1 d=2

p=3 q=7 r=2 s=5 ==> 1 solution a=3 b=1 c=2 d=1

p=3 q=5 r=2 s=7 ==> 1 solution a=4 b=2 c=3 d=1

p=3 q=2 r=5 s=7 ==> no solution ?

p=2 q=7 r=3 s=5 ==> 1 solution a=6 b=2 c=1 d=1

p=2 q=5 r=3 s=7 ==> no solution ?

p=2 q=3 r=5 s=7 ==> 1 solution a=8 b=4 c=2 d=1

Is it  true that there is no solution for p=3,q=2,r=5 and s=7 and p=2,q=5,r=3 and s=7?If yes, why?

When there exists at least one solution with a given equation, is there a finite or an infinite number of solutions?